# For new nodes, how can the cn_target_config_node_list parameter be set in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wonder if this parameter `cn_target_config_node_list` in Apache IoTDB can be configured multiple times? I deleted the ConfigNode file of the cluster master node when IoTDB is running, and then restarted this master node, but the cluster crashed. When I checked the cluster information, I can only see the master node. If this parameter can only be configured once, is there a risk of cluster collapse? And also why did my problem happened?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter `cn_target_config_node_list` is only used when starting and forming the cluster structure for the first time in Apache IoTDB, and will not be needed later. Each node will record the addresses of other nodes, so you don't need to worry about cluster collapse. If the shutdown ConfigNode has been restarted, only the settings of the newly added node needs to be modified and to find a live ConfigNode to join the cluster.